# Problem deploying Rails with Passenger to Mac OS X Leopard Server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, macos, passenger

I'm spinning my wheels... Apache is working and serving static html, png, etc. normally. Trying to get Passenger to serve a rails app out of `www.mydomain.com/rails/`

as it stands when i try to hit my app: `www.mydomain.com/rails/myapp/railsclassname`
I get only an Apache 403 Errors. Nothing in myapp's Production Log.

Apache2 access.log:

```
"GET /rails/ HTTP/1.1" 403 1085
```

Apache2 error.log:

```
[Fri Jun 11 22:44:01 2010] [error] [client 10.0.1.41] File does not exist: /Library/WebServer/wwwroot/rails/railsclassname
```

i've even tried www.mydomain.com/myapp/classname

Passenger, obviously, isn't routing requests made into my sub-folder `rails/` to my rails app. not sure where i've screwed up. the most obvious thing is "**Passenger doesn't seem to be running**"... instructions I've followed just say to `sudo apachectl graceful`, which i've done (as well as stopped/started). new to this so go easy on me!

Here's some info that might be helpful. happy to provide more as needed...

---

As per [some instruction @ Passenger site](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide.html#deploying_rails_to_sub_uri) i've created a symlink from `/Library/WebServer/myapp/rails` -> `/Library/WebServer/rails/myapp/public`

```
myhost:myapp joe$ passenger-config --root
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.14
myhost:myapp joe$ passenger-status
ERROR: Phusion Passenger doesn't seem to be running.
```

apollo:myapp joe$ cat /etc/httpd/httpd.conf

```
...
<removed for brevity>
...
# Copied From Passenger Installer
   LoadModule passenger_module /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.14/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so
   PassengerRoot /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.14
   PassengerRuby /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby
# End Passenger Installer

  NameVirtualHost *

   <VirtualHost *:80>
      ServerName www.mydomain.com
      DocumentRoot /Library/WebServer/rails/myapp/public    # <-- be sure to point to 'public'!
      RackBaseURI /rails
      <Directory /Library/WebServer/rails/myapp/public>
         AllowOverride all              # <-- relax Apache security settings
         Options -MultiViews            # <-- MultiViews must be turned off
         order allow,deny
         Allow from all
      </Directory>
   </VirtualHost>
```

This last bit from NameVirtualHost on is pieced together from a number of online material i've found...as i've been desperately trying to find something/anything that'll show Passenger at least has a pulse!?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you've got

```
www.mydomain.com
www.mydomain.com/rails
```

These both point to different websites (lets call them main and rails), the code for each site might be saved on the file system like so:

```
/Library/WebServer/main/
/Library/WebServer/rails/
```

We create a symlink from your rails app's public folder to a folder called rails in your main app:

```
ln -s /Library/WebServer/rails/public /Library/WebServer/main/rails
```

Then we create a VirtualHost for the main site (not the rails one, and I'm assuming the main site is not rails) and add the rails app as a sub URI, like so:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName www.mydomain.com
  DocumentRoot /Library/WebServer/main
  <Directory /Library/WebServer/main>
    Allow from all
  </Directory>

  RackBaseURI /rails
  <Directory /Library/WebServer/main/rails>
    Options -MultiViews
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

(If you already have a VirtualHost set up for your main website, you can add the RackBaseURI and preceding Directory declaration to that instead).

Now restart apache and you should be able to go to:

```
www.mydomain.com/rails
```

and see the "Welcome to Rails" page, or:

```
www.mydomain.com/rails/controllername
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks! very helpful. and it's working now. kind of. `www.mydomain.com/rails` works but `www.mydomain.com/rails/` does not! Also `www.mydomain.com/rails/controller/new` and `www.mydomain.com/rails/controller` both work BUT `www.mydomain.com/rails/controller/1` and `www.mydomain.com/rails/controller/show/1` do not?!?

Comment: It's because /rails/ is handled by Apache's directory handler.  You can get around this by disabling mod_autoindex in Apache.  RailsAllowModRewrite should be off by default, and this will remove the problem, but some configurations this gets overridden.